# Add url dynamically as event listener to y-axis description with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

with a few questions from here, I was able to add an event listener to my y-axis label. However, I would like to add a different link for each y-axis label so that when you click on a label(in my example the numbers), a new window opens. The link is stored in my CSV, but I have not been able to add it with function(d) {return d.url}. It might be a problem that the y-axis label is created with an array? Does anyone have a solution for this? Here is my code https://codepen.io/Lea12/pen/dyzKEOV

```
var y_axis = d3.scaleBand()
.range([ height, 0 ])
.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.activity; }))
.padding(0.01);

svg2.append("g")
.call(d3.axisLeft(y_axis))
.attr("class","y_axis")
.selectAll("text")
.on("click", function(d){window.open(d.url,"_blank")})
```

My csv looks like this:

group,activity,value,card,url

a,1,50,"card","www.google.de"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only the array of activities is bound to your axis, but you can use the index number to get the url from your data array.

```
svg2.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y_axis).tickFormat(function(d,i) { return data[i].url }))
    .attr("class","y_axis")
    .selectAll("text")
    .on("click", function(d,i){    window.open(data[i].url,"_blank")});
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thank you so much for your contribution